# Scrolling on a fixed element: CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've a div, and a another div is inside that. There are cards inside the second div. Since the first div is fixed I cannot scroll the cards inside the the second div, I need to get those card scrolled. The second div is not mandatory.
The below code are html and its corresponding css.

```css
.HumCategoriesWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* width: 30%; */
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #1C1E2B;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.HomePageWrapper {
  width: 80vw;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div className="HumCategoriesWrapper">
  <h2 style={{paddingTop: "40px", paddingBottom: "20px", width: "100%", color: "white"}}>Hum Categories</h2>
  <div contenteditable className="humCatCards">
    <HomeCard />
    <HomeCard />
    <HomeCard />
    <HomeCard />
    <HomeCard />
    <HomeCard />
    <HomeCard />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max-height` along with `overflow-y: auto` to achieve this.

```css
.HumCategoriesWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* width: 30%; */
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #1C1E2B;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.HomePageWrapper {
  width: 80vw;
  float: right;
}

.humCatCards {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="HumCategoriesWrapper">
  <h2 style={{paddingTop: "40px", paddingBottom: "20px", width: "100%", color: "white"}}>Hum Categories</h2>
  <div contenteditable class="humCatCards">
    <p>
      HomeCard
    </p>
    <p>
      HomeCard
    </p>

    <p>
      HomeCard
    </p>

    <p>
      HomeCard
    </p>

    <p>
      HomeCard
    </p>


  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgsktmy6/1/)